# TFRecords / TensorFlow Serving: Converting TFRecords into (GRPC or RESTFul) TensorFlow Serving requests?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tfrecord

I have a bunch of TFRecords that I used to train a model. I'd like to use them with TensorFlow Serving as well. So far, I've just been using the RESTful TensorFlow serving endpoint and have been turning TFRecords into JSON request bodies.

Is there some special way I can do inference on TFRecords directly without manually munging individual TFRecords into TF serving requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFRecords are binary format, would be hard to pass through RESTFul API directly.
The alternative is to use the GRPC end point of the tf serving. But it may not save you much.

GRPC request requires tensor_proto as input, [see here for an example call](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.py) in Python. In this case, your tensor proto could be a one dimensional data containing a serialized tf.Example object that comes from TFRecord. When you save your model during the training phase, you can define custom serving input processing function, that can accept a serialized tf.Example data as input for serving. Refer to the [tf.estimator.Estimator.export_saved_model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#export_saved_model) on how to define your custom function `serving_input_receiver_fn` for processing inputs at serving time.